# Customize haar cascade classifier for object detection

Tags: opencv, customization, object-detection, haar-classifier, haar-wavelet

I have implemented the haar cascade classification for object detection.
I want to extract daubechies features in the same way and apply a classifier of my interest. How to customize haar cascade classifier in this way?

I have collected positive and negative images, converted them to integral image. I need to find daubechies features from these images and train a classifier.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at the source code. Afaik, the modern cascadeClassifier API is designed object oriented and polymorph, so probably it will be quite easy to understand (compared to the old C-API cascade classifier) and probably you'll only have to implement the Daubechie-Wavelets and not much more of the training/classifier/feature logic.

Comment: the classifier starts with creating haar features.on what basis it is made?how can i do the same for daubechies wavelet